# Javascript Intellisense Message: JS Intellisense:Internal/(1:0) : Function expected

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I am using Visual studio 2010. I have been using it for a long time with out problem. Today I am getting this message every time I try to declare a variable and use it in my javascript files.

```
Javascript Intellisense Message: JS Intellisense:Internal/(1:0) : Function expected
```

What is the reason for this problem?
How can I solve it?

Comment: Show us your code. On which position of it does Intellisense alert?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there aren't any event-activated functions in your HTML that are undefined such as:

```
<select id="selection" onclick="myfunction()"></select>
```

where myfunction() isn't defined anywhere.